# Building static or shared boost libraries with Emscripten

Tags: c++, boost, emscripten, webassembly

Trying to build boost libraries with following commands

```
cd boost_1_68_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 toolset=emscripten link=static variant=release threading=single runtime-link=static system random date_time
```

However it produces `.bc` files to me, not `.a` for `static` build flags or `.so` for `shared` build flags. Then I have problem linking that libraries into my WebAssebly project. How to produce `.a` or `.so` files here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved running

```
# emar q library_name.a *.bc
```

for every `.bc` file in a directory.